# Bilinear Dot Function

Tags: linear-algebra, dot

In mathematics the matrix product is a bilinear operation
$$
\alpha A \cdot(\beta B + \gamma C) = \alpha\beta ( A \cdot B )+ \alpha \gamma (A\cdot C ),
$$
where capital letters denote matrices and greek letters scalars.

Therefore
$$
A \cdot B + A\cdot (-B) = 0.
$$

But it seems this relation is not implemented in Mathematicas `Dot` function, especially

```
Dot[a,b]+Dot[a,-b]
```

does not evaluate to 0. So, how can I define a bilinear matrix product in Mathematica?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Mathematica* is "aware" of linearity of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) in all its arguments, but to exploit it you need to tell *Mathematica* which expressions represent [`Matrices`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Matrices.html), and explicitly ask to expand expression using [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand.html) function:

```
ClearAll[α, β, γ, δ, a, b, c, d, k, l, m, n]
TensorExpand[
    Dot[α a, β b + γ c, δ d],
    Assumptions ->
        a ∈ Matrices[{k, l}] && (b|c) ∈ Matrices[{l, m}] && d ∈ Matrices[{m, n}]
]
(* α β δ a.b.d + α γ δ a.c.d *)
```

You can also use it to exploit $a \cdot b + a\cdot (-b) = 0$ identity:

```
TensorExpand[
    Dot[a, b] + Dot[a, -b],
    Assumptions -> a ∈ Matrices[{m, n}] && b ∈ Matrices[{n, k}]
]
(* 0 *)
```

---

## Old answer using TensorReduce

*Mathematica* is "aware" of $a \cdot b + a\cdot (-b) = 0$ identity for matrices, but you need to tell *Mathematica* that `a` and `b` represent [`Matrices`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Matrices.html), and explicitly ask for "canonical form" using [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce.html):

```
ClearAll[a, b, m, n, k]
$Assumptions = a ∈ Matrices[{m, n}] && b ∈ Matrices[{n, k}];
Dot[a, b] + Dot[a, -b]
% // TensorReduce
(* a.(-b) + a.b *)
(* 0 *)
```

As with any function taking [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) option defaulting to [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), you can localize assumptions by passing them explicitly to `TensorReduce`:

```
TensorReduce[
    Dot[a, b] + Dot[a, -b], 
    Assumptions -> a ∈ Matrices[{m, n}] && b ∈ Matrices[{n, k}]
]
(* 0 *)
```

or by using [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html), as suggested in [comment by Jason B](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109407/bilinear-dot-function/109414#comment296280_109414):

```
Assuming[
    a ∈ Matrices[{m, n}] && b ∈ Matrices[{n, k}],
    Dot[a, b] + Dot[a, -b] // TensorReduce
]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: You could use `Assuming[a \[Element] Matrices[{m, n}] && 
  b \[Element] Matrices[{n, k}],
  Dot[a, b] + Dot[a, -b] // TensorReduce
 ]` to avoid modifying the global `$Assumptions`

Comment: @JasonB Thanks, added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In raw symbolic form, *Mathematica*, simply doesn't know what `a` and `b` in `a.b + a.-b`are, so it doesn't evaluate the expression. However, given a hint ...

```
With[{a = {x, y}, b = {u, y}}, a.b + a.-b]]
```

> `0`

Comment: Slightly simpler:  `With[{a = {x, y}, b = {u, y}}, a.b + a.-b]`

Comment: But Mathematica doesn't have to know anything about `a` and `b`, because the relation holds for all `a` and `b`. Much like `a-a=0`.

Comment: @murphy, but from the documentation "When its arguments are not lists or sparse arrays, `Dot` remains unevaluated."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Good catch. My brain doesn't seem to be fully functional today.

Comment: @murphy : So, when $a$ is a 4-by-3 matrix and $b$ is a 17 element vector, this relation holds?  Remember, if I don't tell you *anything* about the types of $a$ and $b$, they can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

There are small number of rules that make a function [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form), so why not just implement them directly?

```
ClearAll@blDot;
Attributes[blDot] = {OneIdentity, Flat, Orderless};
blDot[Plus[a_, b_], c_] := blDot[a, c] + blDot[b, c];
blDot[Times[a_, b_], c_] := Times[a, blDot[b, c]];
blDot[a_, b_] := Dot[a, b]
```

It works on these examples,

```
blDot[a, (b + c)]
blDot[(a + d), (b + c)]
blDot[a, b] + blDot[a, -b]
(* a.b + a.c *)
(* a.b + a.c + b.d + c.d *)
(* 0 *)
```

But you have to be careful, since `Times` still has the attribute `Orderless` (and I wouldn't recommend changing that), it has no way of knowing which of the multiplied items is a number and which a vector.  So you get this,

```
blDot[A, -α B]
(* -B A.α *)
```

when you might have wanted this

```
(* -α A.B *)
```